# OkHttp enable/disable gzip compression on requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using `Retrofit` to manage my requests and want to make some tests to check de request size using or not using gzip.

By default does `OkHttp` performs gzip compression to requests or it must be implemented with an [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#rewriting-requests)?

I've added

```
@Headers({
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Encoding: gzip"
})
```

or:

```
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json"
})
```

to my requests and did not see any change on the request length.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OkHttp will do transparent gzip on response bodies unless you disable the feature with this header:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

Comment: ... and there's no compression for request bodies. For that you need this: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/RequestBodyCompression.java

Comment: Thanks but I want to gzip the request body and see the differences in size with gzip enabled or disabled. The server is not responding with gzip

Comment: Thanks. for your comment. It's the same has the link I've posted on the OP. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can use this code

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request =  new Request.Builder().url(url)
                                                .addHeader("X-TOKEN", "Bearer " + Auth.getInstance(mContext).getToken())
                                                .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                                                .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

if (responseCode == 200) {
    // Regular JSON parsing to model
    ItemModel itemModel = LoganSquare.parse(response.body().byteStream(), ItemModel.class);
    long responseSize = response.body().contentLength();  

    // Manually decompress GZIP?
    ItemModel itemModel = LoganSquare.parse(new GZIPInputStream(response.body().byteStream()), ItemModel.class);
    long responseSize = response.body().contentLength();    
}
```